# Issues with using PHP within HTML

Tags: php, html

I was trying to test out PHP in HTML on my localhost using this code (in an `.html` file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
   <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>';
   ?>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

And this is the output:

```
Hello World
'; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In a HTML?  Please go through this: http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Comment: rename it to file.php
or configure your webserver (apache,nginx) to handle .html as php.

Comment: if the file extension is .html change it to .php

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

1. Change it to a `.php` file.
2. Configure your webserver to send `.html` files to the PHP processor.

Answer (score 1):

> (in an .html file)

HTML files aren't processed for PHP code server-side.  So you're just returning the code as-is instead of actually running it.  Unless you've explicitly configured your web server to process HTML files as PHP files (which you probably shouldn't do) then you're going to need to make this a `.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

If the file extension is `.html` change it to `.php`.

If it already is a `.php` file then change `<?` to `<?php` it might be that your server does not accept the php shorhand version.

Comment: Why in the world do people downvote a possible answer. At least state what was wrong with it..

Comment: Maybe because three other guys did already say the same thing? idk..

Comment: have you heard of page refreshing through ajax and not seeing the posts?

Answer (score 0):

Add these below lines of code into your `.htaccess file`

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

This will add php to your HTML and HTM filetypes